# Issues with creating a symbolic link (coding Arduino in C)

Tags: cygwin, symlink

I am trying to programme an arduino microcontroller board using C, and I have downloaded the relevant software onto my laptop. When I use cygwin on my windows laptop and try to create a symbolic link using the command: `ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc.exe` it gives me this when I press enter: `ln: failed to create symbolic link './avr-gcc.exe': File exists` eventhough I have the `avr-gcc.exe` saved into cygwin itself.

Answer (score 1):

`ln -s` takes two arguments, the destination of the symlink and the source.
You only give one argument.

Comment: I'm quite new to this so I didn't follow sorry, what other argument would I need to type in?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. A symlink is quite like a copy, you must tell what file should be "copied" and where the new "copy" should be . Here you only give the commands one of these informations:  `/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc.exe`. I don't know what you aim to achieve so I can't help you more than that. You can look for a tutoriel on how to create a symlink if you want more details.